# What is the length property of the array x?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What would the length property of the array x be?

```
var x=new Array(); 
x[0]="Monday"; 
x[1]="Tuesday"; 
x[3]="Thursday";
```

Comment: `x.length` I believe... what exactly is your question?

Comment: Why are you asking such a question? Can't you just inspect `x` yourself?

Comment: @FelixKling I think the OP is asking whether the length will be 3 or 4.

Comment: @Pointy: They can still find this out fairly easily by looking at `x.length`. This may be a legitimate question, but not very useful in its current form (IMO).

Comment: @FelixKling of course you're right; it's interesting to contemplate the impact on answer rates of a general philosophy that questions with answers derivable by trivial experimentation should be ignored :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be 4.

The `.length` property is defined to be one more than the numeric value of the largest integer-like property name. The largest (when interpreted as a number) such property name in the example code is `3`, so the `.length` value is therefor `4`.

If you set a property of an array, such that the property name is an integer (or a string that looks like an integer), then `length` is updated to be one more than that integer value. Symmetrically, if you set `length` to some value, then all properties whose names are integers greater than or equal to the new value are implicitly deleted.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know the length of your array `'x'` then you can just do something like:

`var length = x.length;`

keep in mind that arrays are 0 based. So the length here will be 4, however, if you want to access the indexes of your array you will need to use 0, 1, 2, 3.

further, if you want to know the length, after getting your `var length` you could do either of the following:

```
console.log(length);
alert(length);
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is trying to determine, but this is correct nevertheless.

Comment: I see... needs to be a bit more explicit don't you think?

Comment: Actually the length will be `4`. The array looks like this: `[ "Monday", "Tuesday", undefined, "Thursday" ]`.

Comment: you're right, didn't see the indexes he had. Thank you

Comment: @AbdulAhmad well the OP mentioned the "length" property in the question, so I don't think that's what this is about.